# CONNECT BY with NOCYCLE ( oracle ) hierarhical query in MariaDB with simple sql code

Tags: sql, oracle, mariadb, hierarchical-data, ansi-sql

A hierarchical query with own nocycle solution will be presented.
Improvement needed.

A tree with or without loops (Oidipus) is assumed.
Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `ID` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `PARENT` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `TYPE` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

Fields TYPE and NAME have no importance.Connection is realized with the ID of another person in field PARENT.

1. Find Parents:

```
WITH recursive Parents(ID, SUMID, TYPE, PARENT, LEVEL) AS (
  SELECT ID, Concat(ID,"Z","                  ...") AS SUMID, TYPE, PARENT, 0 AS LEVEL FROM `person` WHERE ID = '1000000005'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT m.ID, CONCAT(m.ID,"Z",SUMID) AS SUMID , m.TYPE, m.PARENT, LEVEL + 1 FROM `person` as m INNER JOIN Parents t on m.ID = t.PARENT
  WHERE LEVEL < 6
  AND INSTR ( SUMID, m.ID) < 1
)
SELECT * FROM Parents;
```

An extra Column SUMID (concatenated "numeric" IDs, separator="Z") will be used for checking NOCCYCLE (see Oracle keyword). (Oidipus appears only one times in field ID).
Works fine, but SUMID initial content should be coded as MAXLEVEL times 10 "String".

What only partially works:

2. Find all Children

```
WITH recursive Children(ID, SUMID, TYPE, PARENT, LEVEL) AS (
  SELECT ID, Concat(ID,"Z","                  ...") AS SUMID, TYPE, PARENT, 0 AS LEVEL FROM `person` WHERE ID = '1000000002'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT m.ID, CONCAT(m.ID,"Z",SUMID) AS SUMID , m.TYPE, m.PARENT, LEVEL + 1 FROM `person` as m INNER JOIN Children t on m.PARENT = t.ID
  WHERE LEVEL < 6
  AND INSTR ( SUMID, m.ID) < 1
)
SELECT * FROM Children;
```

When someone has 5 children and 5*5 = 25 grandchildren, etc., then SUMID could not be long enough.
Furthermore, the script for all children is very slow and weak in performance.
How could you implement "Find all children" in simple MySQL?

I tried to implement a hierarchical query for a tree rekordstructure. The query "Find Children" is slow and iefficient. Ia am hoping for improvement suggestions.

```
INSERT INTO `person` (`ID`, `PARENT`, `TYPE`, `NAME`) VALUES
('1000000001', '1000000001', 'A', 'first'),
('1000000002', '1000000004', 'B', 'second'),
('1000000003', '1000000002', 'C', 'third'),
('1000000004', '1000000002', 'C', 'fourth'),
('1000000005', '1000000004', 'C', 'fifth'),
('1000000006', '1000000002', 'C', '6th'),
('1000000007', '1000000002', 'C', '7th'),
('1000000008', '1000000002', 'C', '8th'),
('1000000009', '1000000002', 'C', '9th'),
('1000000010', '1000000005', 'D', '10th'),
('1000000011', '1000000005', 'D', '11th'),
('1000000012', '1000000005', 'D', '12nd'),
('1000000013', '1000000005', 'D', '13rd');
```

Result:

```
MariaDB [devmysql]> WITH recursive Children(ID, SUMID, TYPE, PARENT, LEVEL) AS (
    ->   SELECT ID, Concat(ID,"Z","                  ") AS SUMID, TYPE, PARENT, 0 AS LEVEL FROM `person` WHERE ID = '1000000002'
    ->   UNION ALL
    ->   SELECT m.ID, CONCAT(m.ID,"Z",SUMID) AS SUMID , m.TYPE, m.PARENT, LEVEL + 1 FROM `person` as m INNER JOIN Children t on m.PARENT = t.ID
    ->   WHERE LEVEL < 6
    ->   AND INSTR ( SUMID, m.ID) < 1
    -> )
    -> SELECT * FROM Children;
+------------+-------------------------------+------+------------+-------+
| ID         | SUMID                         | TYPE | PARENT     | LEVEL |
+------------+-------------------------------+------+------------+-------+
| 1000000002 | 1000000002Z                   | B    | 1000000004 |     0 |
| 1000000003 | 1000000003Z1000000002Z        | C    | 1000000002 |     1 |
| 1000000004 | 1000000004Z1000000002Z        | C    | 1000000002 |     1 |
| 1000000006 | 1000000006Z1000000002Z        | C    | 1000000002 |     1 |
| 1000000007 | 1000000007Z1000000002Z        | C    | 1000000002 |     1 |
| 1000000008 | 1000000008Z1000000002Z        | C    | 1000000002 |     1 |
| 1000000009 | 1000000009Z1000000002Z        | C    | 1000000002 |     1 |
| 1000000005 | 1000000005Z1000000004Z1000000 | C    | 1000000004 |     2 |
| 1000000010 | 1000000010Z1000000005Z1000000 | D    | 1000000005 |     3 |
| 1000000011 | 1000000011Z1000000005Z1000000 | D    | 1000000005 |     3 |
| 1000000012 | 1000000012Z1000000005Z1000000 | D    | 1000000005 |     3 |
| 1000000013 | 1000000013Z1000000005Z1000000 | D    | 1000000005 |     3 |
+------------+-------------------------------+------+------------+-------+
12 rows in set, 11 warnings (0.004 sec)
```

The Oracle equivalent looks like that (see below) :

Hint

In oracle

- UNION ALL is compulsory otherwise
  ORA-32040: recursive WITH clause must use a UNION ALL operation
- a Parameterlist is compulsory otherwise ORA-32039: recursive WITH clause must have column alias list
- recursive ommitted otherwise systax error
- LEVEL is a keyword in ORACLE, i.e. use LEV instead

```
WITH Children (ID, SUMID, LEVEL) 
AS
(
  SELECT
    m.ID,
    ',' || CAST(m.ID AS VARCHAR(120) || ','  AS SUMID,
    0 AS LEV
  FROM
    person  AS m
  WHERE
    ID = '1000000002'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    m.ID,
    t.SUMID || m.ID || ','  AS SUMID,
    LEV + 1 AS LEV
  FROM
    person AS m
  INNER JOIN
    Children AS t
      ON m.PARENT = t.ID
  WHERE
      t.LEV < 10
    AND INSTR(t.SUMID, CONCAT(',', m.ID, ',')) < 1
)
SELECT * FROM Children;
```

Query has delivered ca. 60000 records in 600 msecs.

Query has been tested against his connect by oracle counterpart with **MINUS** in both directions:

```
select ID
FROM person 
  START WITH ID = '1000000002'
  CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR ID = PARENT
MINUS
SELECT ID FROM (
WITH Children (ID, SUMID, LEVEL) 
AS
(
  SELECT
    m.ID,
    ',' || CAST(m.ID AS VARCHAR(120) || ','  AS SUMID,
    0 AS LEV
  FROM
    person  AS m
  WHERE
    ID = '1000000002'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    m.ID,
    t.SUMID || m.ID || ','  AS SUMID,
    LEV + 1 AS LEV
  FROM
    person AS m
  INNER JOIN
    Children AS t
      ON m.PARENT = t.ID
  WHERE
      t.LEV < 10
    AND INSTR(t.SUMID, CONCAT(',', m.ID, ',')) < 1
)
SELECT * FROM Children);
```

Does not deliver any record.

Query was successfully tested in ORACLE in 1 sec. As for me Unbelievable quick.

"Na ja," Connect by can automatically deliver some more features:

- CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE
- CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF
- LEVEL

  [see: oracle docs][1]https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/pseudocolumns001.htm#i1009434]

Comment: can you share some data and the output wanted

Comment: How many children someone has won't affect how long SUMID becomes. It's only the number of generations (recursion depth, or level) that matters.

Comment: I've attached the inserts. 
With 12 Records it the query working. Levels are displayed, looks fine, but would it work with thousand children?
I have got experiences with oracle plan , bit not with MySQL.

Comment: It's NOT the number of children. It's the number of LEVELS that matters.

Comment: I see, You mean, length of SUMID depends only on the number of levels. I got it, thanks.

Comment: Dear @MatBailie,
I've executed
`WITH recursive Children(ID, PARENT, TYPE, NAME) AS (
  SELECT ID, PARENT, TYPE, NAME FROM `person` WHERE ID = '1000000002'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT m.ID, m.PARENT, m.TYPE, m.NAME FROM `person` as m INNER JOIN Children t on m.PARENT = t.ID
)
SELECT * FROM Children;
` 
in fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/Y3CosBiE
i.e. Your query with 4 fields intead of *
I am stunned. Is it in cycle running?  After 2 hours stackoverflow membership is my view of world upside down.
Is with * the default behaviour of MySQL "etwa" noncycle?

Comment: You should read my answer in *full*... It literally says `you can use UNION instead of UNION ALL to prevent loops being evaluated`, but you used UNION ALL any way? https://dbfiddle.uk/c8rJMRx-

Comment: Please also stop calling it MySQL. You're using MariaDB. They were related, years ago, but they're absolutely not the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, deep in MariaDB execution I've missed your precise comment. Yes, time goes by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't need to output the LEVEL and the SUMID, you can use UNION instead of UNION ALL to prevent loops being evaluated.

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `ID` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `PARENT` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `TYPE` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

```
INSERT INTO `person` (`ID`, `PARENT`, `TYPE`, `NAME`) VALUES
('1000000001', '1000000001', 'A', 'first'),
('1000000002', '1000000004', 'B', 'second'),
('1000000003', '1000000002', 'C', 'third'),
('1000000004', '1000000002', 'C', 'fourth'),
('1000000005', '1000000004', 'C', 'fifth'),
('1000000006', '1000000002', 'C', '6th'),
('1000000007', '1000000002', 'C', '7th'),
('1000000008', '1000000002', 'C', '8th'),
('1000000009', '1000000002', 'C', '9th'),
('1000000010', '1000000005', 'D', '10th'),
('1000000011', '1000000005', 'D', '11th'),
('1000000012', '1000000005', 'D', '12nd'),
('1000000013', '1000000005', 'D', '13rd')
;
```

> ```
> Records: 13  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
WITH
  RECURSIVE
    Children
AS
(
  SELECT * FROM `person` WHERE ID = '1000000002'
  UNION
  SELECT m.* FROM `person` as m INNER JOIN Children t on m.PARENT = t.ID
)
SELECT * FROM Children
```

| ID | PARENT | TYPE | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000000002 | 1000000004 | B | second |
| 1000000003 | 1000000002 | C | third |
| 1000000004 | 1000000002 | C | fourth |
| 1000000006 | 1000000002 | C | 6th |
| 1000000007 | 1000000002 | C | 7th |
| 1000000008 | 1000000002 | C | 8th |
| 1000000009 | 1000000002 | C | 9th |
| 1000000005 | 1000000004 | C | fifth |
| 1000000010 | 1000000005 | D | 10th |
| 1000000011 | 1000000005 | D | 11th |
| 1000000012 | 1000000005 | D | 12nd |
| 1000000013 | 1000000005 | D | 13rd |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QNG5EqEa)

Comment: Or, to fix your query, use CAST to ensure you have enough space in the string. ***And*** use *both* leading and trailing separators; `INSTR('101Z202Z303', '3')` will return TRUE, but `INSTR('Z101Z202Z303Z', 'Z3Z')` won't. https://dbfiddle.uk/DWkYTQ6N